# click Once Exception when installing it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, iis-7, clickonce, manifest

i have an application that takes 4 prerequisites: `dotnetfx40` and `ReportViewer` and `vbpowerpacks` and `windowsinstaller3_1` after `publishing` it, i put the `clickonce` folder on a `local network` and create new `application` on the `IIS` to install it from the server to be used by our team.

when i try to install it on any computer, first it install all prerequisites and then installing of the application starts.

during installation, error message appears `Application Installation corrupted` with 2 buttons `OK` and 'Details' if i click `OK` and try to install it from the same `URL`it installed and works fine since all prerequisites was installed.

but if i click `Details` a text documents appears with the following:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.3649
System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.3649 (GDR.050727-3600)
dfdll.dll           : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : http://myhost/myAppl/myAppl.application
                    Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                    X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
Deployment Provider url     : http://myhost/myAppl/myAppl.application
Application url         : http://myhost/myAppl/Application%20Files/myAppl_1_0_0_54/myAppl.exe.manifest
                    Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                    X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : myAppl.application, Version=1.0.0.54, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
Application Identity        : myAppl.exe, Version=1.0.0.54, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.
* Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://myhost/myAppl/myAppl.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Exception occurred loading manifest from file myAppl.resources.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
    + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [10/29/2013 3:32:58 PM] : Activation of http://myhost/myAppl/myAppl.application has started.
* [10/29/2013 3:32:59 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [10/29/2013 3:32:59 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
* [10/29/2013 3:33:02 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
* [10/29/2013 3:33:27 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [10/29/2013 3:34:45 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
    - Exception occurred loading manifest from file myAppl.resources.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
    - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    - Source: 
    - Stack trace:


COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

**Note:** I tried to set application to work to any `CPU` and tried to create application without `manifest` but nothing change

any help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems from the warnings that you need to sign our ClickOnce manifest.  This can be done in your projects settings, under the Signing section.  Also make sure that you are including the resources.dll with your deployment, make sure it is included in the Application Files of the ClickOnce settings.